# identify relevant tokens in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario where one keyword is important in one context, but becomes non-important in another context. I am using elastic search 5.2 to find the relevant results.The data indexed contains human language and sometimes contains location as well.

For eg. if I have the following two texts indexed in elastic search.

```
1)driver jobs in railway colony
2)railway has 25 openings
```

And someone queries for **railway jobs**. How do i ensure that text no.2 gets higher score than text 1.

Is this even possible in elastic search? If not can someone suggest me what should i use for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: obviously organically 1 is more relevant to "railway jobs" than 2. I don't think its possible

Comment: definitely not elastic you have to look for some other NLP techiniques

Comment: WDYM by context? Like based on location? If that's the case - you can use function query based on location like decay function: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay

Comment: in my data i am not getting location directly, or else i would have queried based on location. My data has simple text, and sometimes text also contains location